# Reactjs: How to render HTML tags passing from props

Tags: reactjs, tags, rendering

How could I render any HTML tags passing from `props` .

Ex:

```
props {
 explain: "`<b>`!! Checkin `</b>`"
}
```

I want to render this as per the HTML tag. It can be any tag of `<p>` or `<b>` or `<h2>` or any other .

`{props.explain}` would be **!! Checkin**

Any suggestion here.

Comment: So an html element in a string, parse it and renders correctly? Why not use [`styles`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)?

Comment: @JosephD. any example . please

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) or [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](http://dangerouslySetInnerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

pass an component that returns a plain html, name the props as SomeHtml prop and render it as